# How to download TFS shelveset via browser

Tags: browser, tfs, download, shelveset

Is there an option or plug-in for TFS-Server to provide download the shelveset
via browser.

TFS 2013

Regards
raiserle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download the shleveset, the normal process is [**Unshelve Changes**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets) in Team Explorer, with this you should be able to retrieve the changes in the shelveset into your workspace. If you don't want to use VS, you could give a try  with 3rd-party tool --[**Team Foundation Sidekicks**](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/).

You should also able to query the shelveset info in the web portal through **Team Project- Code- Shelveset**.

[image]

And then either right click the file in the shelveset, select **download** or click **contents** - download file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sidekicks awesome! Download successful ;)
But download via browser? With Sidekicks can i do this - is there no plugin for TFS-Server to provide the download via browser?

Comment: @raiserle You could download it in the browser. However, it's only able to download file one at a time.  More details please see my update in the answer. There is no sidekicks plug-in via browser.